# How to run a cron job every 5 minutes from Saturday 6 am to Monday 6 pm in IST?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling, schedule

I have written this piece of code for **Saturday 6 am** to **Tuesday 6 am** for every **5** minutes-

```
@Scheduled  (cron ="*/5 6-23,23,0-6 * * 6-7,1",zone="IST")
```

But I have to do it for `Monday 6 pm`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split it into two separate cron jobs. The first, similar to the one you already provided in your post - see [this tool](https://crontab.guru/#*/5_6-23,23,0-6_*_*_6-7) for explanation:

```
@Scheduled  (cron ="*/5 6-23,23,0-6 * * 6-7",zone="IST")
```

The second one for Monday, from 6 am till 6 pm:

```
@Scheduled  (cron ="*/5 6-18 * * 1",zone="IST")
```

Answer (score 0):

I divide the scheduler task in 3 timings.
For Saturday and Sunday 6 AM to 11 PM -
`@Scheduled  (cron ="*/5 6-23 * * 6-7",zone="IST")`

For Sunday and Monday 12  to 6 AM -

```
@Scheduled (cron ="* */5 0-6 * * 7,1",zone="IST")
```

For Monday 6 AM to 4 PM-

```
@Scheduled  (cron ="* */5 6-16 * * 1",zone="IST")
```